# Extrude function is locking to a single plain of movement, how do I restore it to normal functionality?

Tags: extrude

I've managed to accidentally lock the extrude function in Blender to a single plain of movement.

When I select a face and then select Extrude by pressing the E key a blue line appears and I'm only able to extrude in a straight line along that particular plain. I'm not pressing XYZ to purposefully do this and  don't know how I turned this function on.

[image]

It's as if I've switched on the orthogonal mode in Autocad.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is default functionality in Blender... If you select "FACE" and hit only E, it extrude in the face orientation of that face, in this case it is straight up

Comment: It didn't used to be like this for me. How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 4):

After tapping E for extrude, just type "z" and then you can move it in any direction you want.